# How does dd write to a device node when you usually can't?

Tags: partitioning, dd

Now usually you'll have a partition on your USB drive or whatever, and you can only write things to there. But dd has the ability to write things outside of partitions, presumably in the MBR. How does it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, partition device nodes (`/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sdb4`, etc.) restrict access to the specified partition; but the whole-disk devices (`/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, etc.) enable access to the entire disk. Partitioning tools (`fdisk`, `gdisk`, GParted, etc.) all work on whole-disk devices, and depending on the partition table type and contents, may write to just about any sector on the disk. The `dd` utility, if applied to a whole-disk device, may read from and write to any sector on the disk, too, by using the `seek`, `skip`, `bs`, and `count` options. (See the `dd` man page for details.)

Note that the MBR is not special in this discussion, except insofar as it's the sector where the MBR partition table is stored. In the context of whole-disk devices, the MBR is simply the first sector on the disk. As such, if you read or write a whole-disk device using `dd`, the MBR will be the first sector read or written (assuming no use of the `seek` or `skip` options). The whole-disk devices give access to *all* sectors of the disk, though, not just the MBR.

Comment: So /dev/sdx just views the storage device as one whole partition, whereas /dev/sdxn views only a single partition on that storage device

Comment: The whole-disk device views the device *as a whole;* partitions don't enter into the picture. *By definition,* a partition is a *part* of a whole device. Every partition-table format of which I'm aware stores partitioning data on the device, and that partitioning data is outside of the partitions themselves, so it's impossible for a partition to cover the *entire* device -- at least one sector (and usually more) is excluded from the partitioned space. This is largely a linguistic distinction, though.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `dd`. Devices are exposed by the kernel. From that you could do whatever you want with them given you have the necessary permission.

`dd` just use them to do its thing.

Comment: So how can you view the contents of the device node? For example, in /dev/sdb not /dev/sdb1?

Comment: `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=63|xxd|less`. You can replace `/dev/sdb` with `/dev/sdb1`